# Mock an XML response using Phoenix the Elixir framework

Tags: elixir

The response body of my HTTP request is XML.  The XML is quite complex and contains may double quotes.
I'd like to mock the response by providing an example of a typical XML response in my code.  I can't seem to find a way to provide the XML as a simple string.
Here's an example from the start of the XML that cause Elixir lots of pain:

```
<Title xmlns="http://website/namespaces/thing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .... >
```

The body response of HTTPoison is body: { ... }.  So I need to provide the XML string inside the tuple without Elixir blowing up. I've tried sigils w/o success.

thanks!

Comment: What sigils did you try? `~s|<Title xmlns="http://website/namespaces/thing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .... >|` works for me, as do triple quotes (`"""`).

Comment: That's the power of sleeping on a problem - I've powered on, resaved and the linter error on Atom has gone.  User error of course, not sure what, but great that ~s does as expected.  Thanks dogbert

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a module attribute:

```
  @xml """
  my xml in here
  """
```

Using sweet_xml I was able to

```
  myparse = parse(@xml)
```

Worked a charm.

I also wanted to investigate the stream_tags function of sweet_xml and saving as a separate .xml file in the lib folder was useful.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to mock an XML response, you could use a library: https://github.com/parroty/exvcr

When you do test for the first time, it will record a request. After that you will use a saved response in a json file.